# How to extract DB name and table name from a comma separated string of Dataframe column to two column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe column "table_name" which is having below string value

tradingpartner.parent_supplier,lookup.store,lab_promo_invoice.tl_cc_mbr_prc_wkly_inv,lab_promo_invoice.mpp_club_card_promotion_funding_view,lab_promo_invoice.supplier_sale_apportionment_cc,tradingpartner.supplier,stores.rpm_zone_location_mapping,lookup.calendar

How to extract DB name and table name from the above string and store it as DB name in one column and tablename in another column.

I want the output as below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to extract the DBName and Table:

```
val result = df.select(
    col("table_name"),
    regexp_replace(col("table_name"), "\\.[^,]+(,|$)", "$1").as("DBName"),
    regexp_replace(col("table_name"), "(^|,)[^,]+\\.", "$1").as("Table")
)

result.show(false)
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|table_name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |DBName                                                                                                  |Table                                                                                                                                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|tradingpartner.parent_supplier,lookup.store,lab_promo_invoice.tl_cc_mbr_prc_wkly_inv,lab_promo_invoice.mpp_club_card_promotion_funding_view,lab_promo_invoice.supplier_sale_apportionment_cc,tradingpartner.supplier,stores.rpm_zone_location_mapping,lookup.calendar|tradingpartner,lookup,lab_promo_invoice,lab_promo_invoice,lab_promo_invoice,tradingpartner,stores,lookup|parent_supplier,store,tl_cc_mbr_prc_wkly_inv,mpp_club_card_promotion_funding_view,supplier_sale_apportionment_cc,supplier,rpm_zone_location_mapping,calendar|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mck for the faster response. I want to save the output DB name and table name in the comma separated value in the same record not multiple record or line

Comment: Edited the question. I added the output as a image. I want the output as table_name DBname Tablename in a single record

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I am getting below error if I run the above command.org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
extraneous input '>' expecting {'(', 'SELECT'..== SQL ==
array_join(transform(table_name2,x-> split(x,'\\.')[0]),',') as dbname

Comment: could you please help me here for the above error.

Comment: scala> val result = df.select(col("table_name"), split(col("table_name"), ",").as("table_name2")).selectExpr("table_name","array_join(transform(table_name2,x -> split(x,'\\\\.')[0]),',') as dbname","array_join(transform(table_name2, x -> split(x, '\\\\.')[1]), ',') as Table")
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
extraneous input '>' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD',
array_join(transform(table_name2,x -> split(x,'\\.')[0]),',') as dbname
------------------------------------^^^
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:239)

Comment: for the below string bakery',`lab_online_analytics`.`cap_adobe_classifications_ghs_product`,sauces','plant ' I want output only lab_online_analytics as DB name  but currently I am getting as bakery',`lab_online_analytics`,sauces','plant as DB name this is wrong. Can you please suggest something.

Comment: @Siva would you mind opening another question for that please? It's hard to answer it here in the comments with limited space. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I wrote the UDF for your requirement in Java, but I think its easy to convert to Scala.

```
//Spark >= 2.3
UserDefinedFunction splitTableNameUDF = udf(transformTables(), getTableName());
df.withColumn("table_name_new", splitTableNameUDF.apply(col("table_name")))
    .select("table_name", "table_name_new.DBName", "table_name_new.Table");


//Spark < 2.3

sqlContext.udf().register("splitTableNameUDF", transformTables(), getTableName());
df.withColumn("table_name_new", callUDF("splitTableNameUDF", col("table_name")))
    .select("table_name", "table_name_new.DBName", "table_name_new.Table");

//schema

public static StructType getTableName() {
    List<StructField> inputFields = new ArrayList<>();
    inputFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("DBName", DataTypes.StringType, true));
    inputFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("Table", DataTypes.StringType, true));
    return DataTypes.createStructType(inputFields);
}


//UDF

public static UDF1<String, Row> transformTables() {
    return (row) -> {
        String[] dbtableNames = row.split(",");
        List<String> dbNames = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String dbtableName : dbtableNames) {
            String[] split = dbtableName.split(".");
            dbNames.add(split[0]);
            tableNames.add(split[1]);
        }
        return RowFactory.create(String.join(",", dbNames), String.join(",", tableNames));
    };
}
```